# Re-use the dropdown for all the td in a table

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a p-table in which the last column contains three dots that open a dropdown menu.
The dropdown menu position is fixed and does not suit the position of the td element of each row.

HTML code:

```
  <td width="80" class="grp-list">
      <a (click)="myFunction()">
      <div class="test">
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a >Home</a>
          <a >About</a>
          <a >Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS file:

```
     .test:after {
content: '\2807';
font-size: 20px;
//position: relative;

    }


   .grp-list{
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
   .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     z-index: 1;
    }
  .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: SFR;
}

.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

 }
```

ts file:

```
myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document. If the HTML shown is repeated for each row, the HTML is invalid, and `getElementById` will return the first element with the ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the JavaScript result always return first value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214427/why-the-javascript-result-always-return-first-value)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse that css you can create a [Mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) with scss, it allows you to reuse it.

Or you just can make that a component having a content input with the same css that you have there.